# Bootstrap 5 - offcanvas component not displayed in vue 3 app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-5, off-canvas-menu

I'm trying to integrate the new offcanvas component of bootstrap 5 in my vue app. I have this code and after the app is build I'm tying to test it but I'm not able to see the offcanvas menu. I don't have loaded the js plugin to mantain my app light and I'm adding the show class using a variable that will bind the needed class. How I can fix it?

```html
<template>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-collapse bg-light fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <span class="float-start">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" @click.prevent="showOffcanvasMenu()">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" :class="showMenu ? '' : 'show'" tabindex="-1">
      <div class="offcanvas-header">
        <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="">Offcanvas with backdrop</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" @click.prevent="showOffcanvasMenu()"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="offcanvas-body">
        <p>.....</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  
  <!-- <div class="container-fluid bg-light p-0" v-show="isLoading">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <div class="spinner-grow text-primary" role="status">
          <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
        </div>    
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> -->

  <router-view/>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data(){
    return {
      showMenu: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showOffcanvasMenu(){
      this.showMenu ? this.showMenu = false : this.showMenu = true;
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  //color: #2c3e50;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few issues.

*First*, the `:class` conditional logic is reversed, it should be:

```
:class="showMenu ? 'show' : ''"
```

*Secondly* (the larger issue), is that simply toggling the `show` class isn't going to work to control display of the Offcanvas element. The Offcanvas JS component does more than toggle the `show` class. It also changes the `visibility` property and hooks up several other methods/events.

**Workarounds**

1 - One option would be to not use Vue to toggle the Offcanvas element and simply use the vanilla JS `data-bs-` attributes.

*or,*

2 - Another option is to also toggle the `visibility` property of the element based on the value of `showMenu`...

```
:style="{ visibility: showMenu ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/vHAJkdaTLq#)

*or,*

3 - Create a Vue wrapper component for Bootstrap's Offcanvas component.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I've noticed the `visibility` about the offcanvas and I've added a rule in my scss ruleset to modify the visibility when the variable I have to show the menu is set to true.

Comment: To achieve it without a custom function:  
  
1. The trigger button toggles $showMenu:  
`<button class="btn btn-primary" @click.prevent="showMenu = !showMenu" ... >`  
  
2. The offcanvas div toggles 'show' and 'visible' classes together:  
`<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" :class="{'show visible':showMenu}"... >`  
  
3. The offcanvas header's close button toggles $showMenu:  
`<button @click.prevent="showMenu = !showMenu"... >`  
  
4. Result: the only required JS is:  
    `new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data(){
        return { showMenu: false }
      }
    })`

Comment: I know, old post, but why does the dark backdrop not appear like in the Bootstrap demo?